# Combine a uint32 with 32 MSB of uint64 to get a value

Tags: c, timestamp

I have a timestamp that is truncated and I am getting the value as uint32. In order to recover it I will need to combine it with the MSB(bit63~32) of the RTC time (uint64) that I am getting.
An example of values is this:
uint32_t sensor_ts=1897792412;
uint64_t clock_ts=1665471940315;

How could I form the new timestamp?

Comment: perhaps bitwise operators is what you are looking for? you can get the upper bits from a number by doing something like this A & 0x111111111100000000. (& and && are not the same thing!)

Comment: Problem with is that this is potentially dangerous – if you get the (truncated) timestamp shortly before the 32-bit sub-value overflows and the full value later on is read *after* the overflow then your final timestamp performs a huge jump into the future!

Comment: @Aconcagua ... or into the past, depending on which clock is fast and which is slow and the delay between amputation and the Frankenstein operation suggested here... Not advised....

Comment: Better technique may be to perform backflips to determine clock discrepancy, then use that delta with the "local" full-width value to restore what _should_ have been received... Track and maintain the delta between readings...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I assumed the same clock being read – two clocks involved (would have been my next question) indeed make all the matter much worse.

Comment: Why do you need the full timestamp at all? If you are measuring time differences then the 32-bit might be enough, depending on the time spans you measure.

Comment: @Aconcagua "Frame shifting"  It's like dealing with a friend living in another timezone, especially, for instance, across the Pacific... 10AM here is 6PM there, but there's a dateline, too, to consider... Delta is, from my perspective, -16hr (until DST starts here and ends there some other Sunday.) Can be done, but involves a bit of thought... :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 *'Can be done'* – depends. You need to know 1. which clock is read first (in absolute time; we know in example) 2. both clocks have a fix difference one to another (given in example if reading same clock both times) 3. both times are read *within one day* (or in example with in the range of 32 bit).

Comment: You might safely restore the full value only if some pre-conditions are met: 1. You read both values from the same clock. 2. You can *absolutely* guarantee that time difference between reading the truncated value and reading the full value afterwards *always* occurs within a timespan of *less than `2^32` time ticks*. In that case you could do `full & 0xffffffff00000000 | truncated - ((full & 0xffffffff < truncated) << 32)` – the subtracted value is either 0 or 2^32 depending on the comparison resulting in true/1 or false/0 – which is the overflow detection.

Comment: @Aconcagua I've known people who had set their watches (pre-internet/smartphone device for tracking local time) 5-10 _ahead_ of local time to reduce missing busses/trains... Things can be _managed_ with knowing the delta (presuming reasonable behaviour from all sources. Forgetting about a DST change is one cause of disruption...)

Comment: You don't even need to know the exact delta – and delta even can vary. The only thing that must not occur is these deltas exceeding the range of one day – or to be precise: They must be within the range of a fix, known offset and this offset plus one day.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint64_t tstmp = sensor_ts | (clock_ts & ((~(uint64_t)0) << 32));
```

You should use bit masks here. To get the upper 32 bits of `clock_ts`, you can use a mask, with the upper 32 bits set. In my example I do this with an fully set uint64_t (111..111, 64 times 1). I shift it to the left by 32 bits, so the lower 32 bits are 0 (111...000, 32 times 1 and 32 times 0). Now I use the bitwise and operator, to zero out the lower 32 bits of clock_ts. And finally use the bitwise or operator to create the combined timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you think binary do not use decimal numbers only hex or octal.

```
uint32_t sensor_ts = 0x711e039c; uint64_t clock_ts = 0x00000183c5dd06dbll;
```

To replace upper 32bits:

You can use bitwise operations

```
uint64_t combine(const uint32_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    y &= (((uint64_t)1 << 32) - 1);  // reset upper 32 bits
    y |= (uint64_t)x  << 32;        // set upper 32 bits
    return y;
}
```

or union if you know the endianness (in this case little endian)

```
uint64_t combine1(const uint32_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    union
    {
        uint64_t y;
        uint32_t x[2];
    }u64 = {.y = y};

    u64.x[1] = x;
    return u64.y;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/asdTEK9Ka

Or to replace lower 32bits:

```
uint64_t combine(const uint32_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    y &= ~(((uint64_t)1ULL << 32) - 1);  // reset lower 32 bits
    y |= x;        // set lower 32 bits
    return y;
}

uint64_t combine1(const uint32_t x, uint64_t y)
{
    union
    {
        uint64_t y;
        uint32_t x[2];
    }u64 = {.y = y};

    u64.x[0] = x;
    return u64.y;
}

int main(void)
{
     uint32_t sensor_ts=1897792412; uint64_t clock_ts=1665471940315;

     printf("%016"PRIx32" %016"PRIx64"\n", sensor_ts, clock_ts);
     printf("%016"PRIx64" %016"PRIx64"\n", combine(sensor_ts, clock_ts), combine1(sensor_ts, clock_ts));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/YxxTM5f6E

Comment: The shift version is always the correct one. There's no point in making the program needlessly non-portable by using unions.

Comment: @Lundin imo it is good to show alternatives